# how to find item in mongo collection when _id is object?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have mongo collection which have _id key as object of 2 key value pair. (_id = {"id":123, "slice":1}). how can I use pymongo find() to fetch an item using _id? sample collection item looks like this. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `uuid` module as follows:

```py
db.foo.drop()

import uuid
uu = uuid.uuid4()
uu2 = uuid.uuid4()

db.foo.insert_one({'_id':{'execution_id':uu, 'slice':1}, 'realm':'bar'})
print("should find it:", db.foo.find_one({'_id':{'execution_id':uu, 'slice':1}}))
print("should NOT find it:", db.foo.find_one({'_id':{'execution_id':uu2, 'slice':1}}))
```